# Refactoring Java Servlets - Looking for a good naming scheme

Tags: java, design-patterns, servlets, refactoring

I'm refactoring an existing (Ajax) Java Web application, which currently holds lots of its logic directly in the servlets. (The servlets even call each other, using a few nasty tricks ...)

The refactoring itself is painful, but pretty much straightforward (refactoring everything to use Dependency Injection now).

My problem is, that I really can't come up with the perfect naming scheme:

The refactored Servlets are now holding just a minimum amount of logic (just so much that they process the ServletRequest and ServletResponse, send an HTTP error code, etc.), then they call what I currently refer to as **Processors** (good/bad name?!?), which can be reused by several Servlets, Test classes, ... The processors perform the logic required for the action, similar to what a Session Bean would do if we were using EJBs.

I never thought, that "Session Bean" would be a good name anyway. And I'm also not very keen on defining a monolithic "Facade". I'm looking primarily for a better name than "Processor", or maybe some ideas how *you* structure your Servlet processing code.

### Example

This is a simplified example (the real application uses GWT with Gilead, ... but that's not so important):

```
public class UserRegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Inject
UserRegistrationProcessor userRegistrationProcessor;

@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req, 
        final HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = parseRegistrationRequest(req);

    RegistrationResult registrationResult = 
                userRegistrationProcessor.process(registrationRequest);

    pw.print(toJson(registrationResult));

    ...
}
}
```

As the example suggests, I prefer to have specialized processors, which are responsible for one task only (or maybe a few very strongly related tasks) - opposed to a big class that handles lots of different actions.

Comment: I call my parts View, Model and the logic part Controller. ;)

Comment: @cularis: The Model/View/Controller part of the application resides on the (JavaScript) client side (it's a full blown GWT/GXT rich internet application, there are no dynamic web pages etc). The servlets just process the interaction between the client and the server.

Comment: How about 'services' instead of processors? You could create these using a factory (Spring maybe) and inject them into your servlets as needed.

Comment: @Adriaan: Not bad, I'm thinking about it... It's a bit generic maybe - a problem that the word shares with 'processor'.

Comment: I think 'Service' is the accepted architectural name for a wrapper of business logic. Maybe if you provide some more context I could come up with an appropriate, less generic name. But so far I really feel you are talking about services.

Comment: @Adriaan: Good idea, I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Why do you need to keep the request/response paradigm of servlets going in the associated class? You could abstract away from servlets even further by first extracting the data from the request in your servlet code or, if this leads to a lot of duplication, you can reuse a separate collaborating class for that task. Then call your userRegistrationSERVICE with the meaningful parameters. If this is not clear I can create an answer with a code example of what I mean.

Comment: @ChrisLercher let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2019/discussion-between-adriaan-koster-and-chris-lercher)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my example based on previous discussion:

```
public class UserRegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private UserRequestExtractor userRequestExtractor;

    @Inject
    private UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.print(createResponse(userRequestExtractor.extract(request)));
    }

    protected String createResponse(User newUser) {
        if (newUser == null) {
            return "{'message' : 'the user parameters are not valid'}";
        }
        else {
            UserRegistrationResult result = userRegistrationService.register(newUser);
            switch (result) {
                case SUCCESS:
                    return "{'message' : 'hurray'}";
                case EMAIL_IN_USE:
                    return String.format("{'message' : 'the email address %s is already in use'}", newUser.email);
                case USERNAME_IN_USE:
                    return String.format("{'message' : 'the user name %s is already in use'}", newUser.username);
                default:
                    return "{'message' : 'an error occurred'}";
            }
        }
    }
}

public class User {
    private String username;
    private String email;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return username != null && email != null;
    }
}

/**
 * Extractor which instantiates an object of type T from a request
 * 
 * @param <T>
 */
public interface RequestExtractor<T> {
    public T extract(HttpServletRequest request);
}

public class UserRequestExtractor implements RequestExtractor<User> {
    public User extract(HttpServletRequest request) {
        User user = new User();
        user.username = request.getParameter("username");
        user.email = request.getParameter("email");
        // validation could also be a responsibility of the RequestExtractor
        if (!user.isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return user;
    }
}

public interface UserRegistrationService {
    public UserRegistrationResult register(User user);
}

// implementation of UserRegistrationService omitted

public enum UserRegistrationResult {
    SUCCESS, EMAIL_IN_USE, USERNAME_IN_USE;
}

/**
 * Unit test
 */
public class UserRegistrationServletTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        UserRegistrationServlet cut = new UserRegistrationServlet();
        User user = new User();
        user.username = null;
        user.email = "test@test.test";

        String response = cut.createResponse(user);

        Assert.assertEquals("{'message' : 'the user parameters are not valid'}", response);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the comprehensive example (actually, this is more than I needed :-)! It convinces me, that the term "Service" can work well!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! One addition: the generation of JSON response contents could of course be outsourced to some JSON-generating associate of the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not call them what they are: `Servlet`s?

As in:

```
com.mycompany.app.admin.user.SaveServlet.java
com.mycompany.app.admin.user.ListServlet.java
```

Comment: A (HTTP) servlet is just a connection point between a HTTP request and your program. It should only perform tasks that are very specific to transform the HTTP request/response model into API calls. Why? Because it's hard and unnatural to re-use a servlet. You almost can't (cleanly) test it - because it basically requires a servlet container. Moreover, you may want to reuse the logic with a very different interface (let's say, calling an action as part of a batch job)... Bottom line is, that business logic does not belong in a Servlet.

Comment: @chris: you didn't mention what your application structure looks like. It was just an example, having many servlets led me to believe you're still putting some of your business logic into the servlets.

A `Servlet` is still a servlet though, I stick to the idea that you should call them: `WhatEverItDoesOrHandlesServlet` (TM) ;)

Comment: It's possible, that I will eliminate the multiple-servlet structure altogether, and replace it with a Command pattern. This would leave just one single servlet, with one service method, which can then delegate to the API. I'm not sure, if I will take this step or not, and as long as I'm not, of course my servlets have names like the ones you suggest (they've always had). My question however is about the layer behind the servlets :-)

Comment: Why can't you test Servlets? You can pass mock ServletRequest/-Response objects into your service method or you can extract the business logic into separate methods and unit test those (admittedly leaving the request parameter extraction etc. code untested in that case).

Comment: @Chris: I thought you're set on `Processor`s and perhaps missed a bit the real question. Struts 1 has `ActionServlet` and `Action`s, you have `CommandServlet` and `Processor`s

Comment: @Adriaan: Everything can be tested, somehow... if all else fails, one can always use JMockit :-) It's just all very hard and unnatural, and doesn't fit well with the whole concept of Dependency Injection, Test Driven Development etc. And if something is unnatural to test, it's usually a sign of a problem with the code. And actually, the existing code suffers from exactly these problems (as I mentioned, one Servlet called another one, and to do that, it had to manipulate the threadLocalRequest - a concept in GWT RemoteServiceServlets, ...)

Comment: In modern day frameworkia I always seem to need one of the mock frameworks to unit test. To me that is not hard or unnatural anymore. Despite that, some code is still notably hard to unit test, like code that interacts with the file system or the network. I usually settle for scoped integration tests there. When I encounter straight-up servlets these can usually be (partially) tested without too much problems in my experience. That said, the code you working one seems to have some issues that might make this harder (-:

Comment: @Adriaan - I typically prefer not to do so. I typically de-couple infrastructure and html/mime/session book-keeping on the servlet, with app-specific logic in some sort of controller class who "decides" which view and model to use (or simply computes the model which is passed to the view obtained form the servlet.) Either way, bizness actions like "save" or "list" go into (hopefully) servlet-agnostic and (within reason) framework agnostic controllers named after the app-specific actions they perform. Servlets are named after the "infrastructure/plumbing" non-bizness actions they perform.

Comment: @Adriaan - just a personal preference as neither approach is intrinsically better or worse **in the general case**.